# pandas merge column by another column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel, named `df1` and `df2`.

df1.columns : `url, content, ortheryy`

df2.columns : `url, content, othterxx`

Some contents in df1 are empty, and df1 and df2 share some urls(not all).
What I want to do is fill df1's empty content by df2 if that row has same url.

I tried

```
ndf = pd.merge(df1, df2[['url', 'content']], on='url', how='left') 
# how='inner' result same
```

Which result:

two column: content_x and content_y

[image]

I know it can be solve by loop through df1 and df2, but I'd like to do is in pandas way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['content'] = df1['content'].combine_first(ndf['content_y'])
```

Or:

```
df1['content'] = df1['content'].fillna(ndf['content_y'])
```

It works, because `left join` create in `ndf` same index values as `df1`.